# google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){}) vs window.onload = function(){}

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

What is the purpose of google's api having a method for assigning event handlers? Why would I use:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){});
```

over

```
window.onload = function()
```

Comment: …or `window.addEventListener('load',function(){})` for that matter…

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#event) it’s just a cross-browser way of adding event listeners. Just like jQuery’s event listener methods.

Comment: @Xufox I see, so just another cross-browser option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Google Maps JavaScript API event model creates and manages its own custom events. However, the DOM (Document Object Model) within the browser also creates and dispatches its own events, **according to the particular browser event model in use**. If you wish to capture and respond to these events, the Maps API provides the `addDomListener()` static method to listen to and bind to DOM events.
>
> `addDomListener()` simply passes the indicated event to the browser, which handles it **according to the browser's DOM event model**; however, almost all modern browsers at least support DOM Level 2. (For more information on DOM level events, see the [Mozilla DOM Levels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) reference.)

[Read the complete documentation on DOM events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents).